# Fast OS for embedded system

Tags: c

I'm creating a project with raspberry pi and I need an "os" which boots in a few seconds when the power is turned on. The os has to have the following features:

- audio driver (3.5mm)
- c/c++ running ability with sdl library
- ability to mount usb (or an other way to transfer files)
- ability to install few little packages when needed (apt)

I know about Buildroot so dont't mention about it :)

Comment: Unfortunately you won’t find a readymade solution for this. Your requirements would need heavy customizations.

Comment: You could use raspbian and strip it to your needs.

Comment: I would look into one of the real-time OS's for the pi, and disable everything you don't need (especially the graphical interface) - you might also want to look [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=56413) for a system that boots in 3-5 seconds (but I don't think it has all of your requirements, so you will need to tweak it..)

you will also need to experiment and find the fastest SD card that you can use with the pi's limited current to the SD card.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution.

[www.emdebian.org](http://www.emdebian.org/)

This project produces minimised packages, a debian-based environment, and complete distributions for specific types of devices.